# request.form for dropdownlist value

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to get value of selected item of dropdownlist using Post Method (request.form).

```
request.form["DropDownList"];
```

how can i get selectedvalue ,selectedindex or selecteditem.text ....

Comment: I'm assuming you are doing this because the form post is coming from a different page? If that's the case, then you don't have the ability to access properties of the listbox like SelectedValue, SelectedItem, etc. because that object does not exist. If you are doing this on the same page, then there is a way.

Comment: yes, i need to access a dropdownlist from a previous page .

Comment: Actually, there are cases where you can. "IF" you are doing a cross page postback

Answer (score 5):

Try this (assuming the ID of your `DropDownList` is `DropDownList1`:

```
Request.Form[DropDownList1.UniqueID]
```

Comment: This simple answer is what I was looking for. I didn't know about the UniqueID property, and it solved my problem when I came here from a web search. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This way you can obtain a selected value.

```
string value=Request.Form["DropDownList1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the method you are requesting. It can't be done.

That being said. If you are doing a Cross Page Postback, then that is one case where you can access the previous pages objects in it. Otherwise, if you don't have that type of control, then, you likely can't get to them.

In simple terms, you'd do a form on Page1.aspx like so

```
<form PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" runat="server" id="frm">
```

On Page2.aspx, along with some other code, using the **PreviousPage**, you can do something like so:

```
((DropDownList)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("DropDownList")).SelectedValue;
```

References:

[How to: Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)

[Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtains the value from

```
Request.Form["DropDownList1"]
```

but if the ID of the drop down list is not static, you can do this..

Create a temporary static variable in some global.cs file

```
public class Global
{
    public static string ddlID="";
}
```

and in .aspx.cs file where the drop down list is place.

```
Global.ddlID = DropDownList1.UniqueID
```

and on post pack

```
if (this.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == Globals.ddlID) {
//Perform action here, This postback is caused by **DropDownList1**
}
```